# The 'Start button' doesn't always work in Ubuntu Studio 14.04

Tags: 14.04, button

I'm not sure what it's called in Ubuntu, but the Ubuntu Studio logo that's analogous to the place of the windows start button, doesn't always work. If I've been using it in the last couple of minutes the menu comes down fine, but if I come back to it after a while of not using it I'll click on it, it'll highlight, but the menu doesn't come down. I'll click elsewhere and come back to it a little while later and it'll work fine. It's not a major problem, but does anyway know what it could be.

And what it's actually called would be good to know as well.

ls_usb -a returns:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

if that helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

They call it Dash. Maybe it is related to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1371590 that has something to do with the activation area. If not maybe you can create a bug report with screenshots.